# using bash, create files based on pattern match

Tags: bash, awk, sed

we have a file with content as below.

```
/* ----------------- pattern_1 ----------------- */ 

jb: pattern_1  
Data:
asdflj 
adfas
Log: dir/log1

/* ----------------- pattern_2 ----------------- */ 

jb: pattern_2   typ: CM
comm: ${dir}/DISPV
mach: au_buh
description: "run flag"


/* ----------------- pattern_3 ----------------- */ 

jb: pattern_3   typ: fw 
own: buh
out_file: "${log}/jl.log"
err: "log.err"
```

the file has to be split into 3 and create as 3 separate files as below:

*pattern_1.txt*

```
/* ----------------- pattern_1 ----------------- */ 

jb: pattern_1  
Data:
asdflj 
adfas
Log: dir/log1
```

*pattern_2.txt*

```
* ----------------- pattern_2 ----------------- */ 

jb: pattern_2   typ: CM
comm: ${dir}/DISPV
mach: au_buh
description: "run flag"
```

*pattern_3.txt*

```
/* ----------------- pattern_3 ----------------- */ 

jb: pattern_3   typ: fw 
own: buh
out_file: "${log}/jl.log"
err: "log.err"
```

tried "awk pattern matching", didn't work out. any help ??

Comment: Does any of [these Q&As](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=split+file+on+pattern) help?

Comment: Have a look at `csplit`

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1501375/80864

Comment: @team 9 - [edit] your question to show your attempt so we can help you, just saying `tried "awk pattern matching"` doesn't demonstrate any effort, nor does it show us where you need help in your coding which is what this forum exists to provide, not free code.

Comment: Also, the most important part of the problem is what `pattern_<N>` really looks like - show truly representative examples of such "patterns" rather than just that presumably placeholder string.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's [cross-posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/361691) and has several answers on the other site, https://askubuntu.com/q/1501375/1722986.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping these pattern comments in `file`:

```
awk '/\/\* -{17} [a-z0-9_]+ -{17} \*\// {if (x) close(x); split($0,a," "); if (a[3] != "") {x=a[3]".txt"} else {next}} {if (x) print > x}' file
```

This is an approximation where you need to have always the symbol -  17 times like you main file, and awk will search this string to know when to start and cut the content. Therefore it will provide a txt file for each pattern section of main file.

Comment: 1) Instead of `[a-z0-9_]` use `[[:alnum:]_]` because  `[a-z0-9_]` will match different sets of characters in different locales, character classes avoid that problem. 2) Instead of `if (x) close(x)` use just `close(x)` as that function will already do nothing if `x` isn't null (and that wouldn't fail if your output file name was `0`). 3) Instead of `split($0,a," ")` do `split($0,a)` since FS is a blank char by default. 4) Instead of `split($0,a," "); if (a[3] != "")` just do `($3 != "")`, you don't need to call `split()` as $0 is already split into $1, etc.

Comment: 5) Instead of `if (a[3] != "") {x=a[3]".txt"} else {next}` just do `x=$3".txt"` - your initial regexp already guarantees there are more than 3 fields. 6) Instead of `{if (x) print > x}` do `x{print > x}` to be more idiomatic wrt awks `<condition>{<action>}` structure.

Comment: So your code could just be `awk '/\/\* -{17} [[:alnum:]_]+ -{17} \*\// {close(x); x=$3".txt"} x{print > x}' file` (and you could just do `{print > x}` instead of `x{print > x}` if the OPs input always looks like their example and starts with a `/* ... */` line). Of course, this approach fails if `pattern_<N>` can contain white space or `/`s so YMMV.

Comment: Hi @mrexojo, thanks much for the code. It's perfectly working. 

Since the number: 17 ( no of "-") is not consistent, modified match as: /\/\*.*[a-z0-9_]+.*\*\//

could you please explain below logic, I didn't quite get it..
{if (x) close(x); split($0,a," "); if (a[3] != "") {x=a[3]".txt"} else {next}} {if (x) print > x}

Answer (score 0):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
/* ----------------- pattern_1 ----------------- */ 

jb: pattern_1  
Data:
asdflj 
adfas
Log: dir/log1

/* ----------------- pattern_2 ----------------- */ 

jb: pattern_2   typ: CM
comm: ${dir}/DISPV
mach: au_buh
description: "run flag"


/* ----------------- pattern_3 ----------------- */ 

jb: pattern_3   typ: fw 
own: buh
out_file: "${log}/jl.log"
err: "log.err"
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="/[*]"}/./{fname=$2 ".txt";sub(/[[:space:]]*$/,"");print "/*"$0 > fname;close(fname)}' file.txt
```

creates `pattern_1.txt` holding

```
/* ----------------- pattern_1 ----------------- */ 

jb: pattern_1  
Data:
asdflj 
adfas
Log: dir/log1
```

and `pattern_2.txt` holding

```
/* ----------------- pattern_2 ----------------- */ 

jb: pattern_2   typ: CM
comm: ${dir}/DISPV
mach: au_buh
description: "run flag"
```

and `pattern_3.txt` holding

```
/* ----------------- pattern_3 ----------------- */ 

jb: pattern_3   typ: fw 
own: buh
out_file: "${log}/jl.log"
err: "log.err"
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that row separator (`RS`) is `/` followed by literal `*` (without `[` `]` `*` would be understood as zero-or-more repeats), then for each non-empty row (`/./`, there is empty row before first `/*`) I create `fname` by concatenating 2nd column value with `.txt` (I assume pattern never contains any whitespace), strip trailing white-space characters using [`sub` string function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html), then I `print` such changed row prefixed by `/*` (i.e. row separator) to file named `fname`, then I close `close` function to prevent malfunction for big number of elements in single file.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*